# Using Tasks recursively in C# without ThreadStarvation

Tags: java, c#, multithreading, recursion, task

I am trying to figure out if concurrent programming (Specifically with TaskScheduler, TaskFactory) in **C#** can lead to ThreadStarvation.

I created a fixed Threadpool in **Java** for a divide and conquer sort algorithm, a Task tries to
create 2 new Childtasks and waits for their results to merge them. While a Task waits, the used Thread needs to wait. At some point the Threadpool can't create more Threads and the program crashes. You can fix this by using fork/join-tasks that can jump to some other work after they forked and wait for the results.

Can this phenomenon happen in C# as well?
Are there also ForkJoinTasks for recursive algorithms or are they not needed because the usual Tasks can prevent this?
I'm having problems finding something about the behaviour of tasks when they wait for child tasks.

Comment: Sure, just use the `Task.Run` to create a number of long-running delegate-based tasks equal to the cores of your machine, and the `ThreadPool` is already saturated. Are you interested for an example that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: I would be more interested in a concept that can prevent creating too many threads and reusing them while waiting for child results from tasks.

Comment: So basically something equivalent to javas RecursiveTask<>

Comment: You can create your own `ThreadPool` and `TaskScheduler` which limits the number of threads. But you appear to be confusing two concepts: tasks and threads. A task [does not *necessarily* use up a thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) just by existing, it only uses up a thread when code is actually executing. So the parent task doesn't use up any threads while waiting, if coded correctly. And if you are asking about [tag:c#] why tag this question with [tag:java]?

Comment: In C#, a thread that is awaiting the result of a task, will be free to perform another task in the mean time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using async/await you should not get thread starvation since awaiting a task does not block any thread.

If you are using `.Wait()` or `.Result` on your task, the thread will block, and starvation is very likely. The threadpool will add threads in an attempt to alleviate the starvation, but this process is *slow*, so your program will likely appear to hang. In any case, using a huge amount of threads is just a bad idea.

For something like sorting you probably do not want to start tasks recursively since the overhead will likely start to dominate once the individual chunks start to become smaller. So I would probably recommend switching to a single threaded strategy after a few recursions to avoid this. Or just split the input into N equally sized buckets, where N is the number of cores available, process these buckets in parallel and merge the result. That should help minimize the threading overhead.